# In SQL query, how do you get the SUM of another SUM?

Tags: sql, function, sum, aggregate

```
SELECT b.BranchName, SUM(SUM(ob.FirstQty + ob.SecondQty))* ps.Price TotalCost
FROM Branch b, Product_Supplier ps, Product p, Supplier s, Order o, Order_Details od
WHERE o.BranchID = b.BranchID
AND o.OrderID = ob.OrderID
AND ob.ProductID = p.ProductID
AND p.FirstSupplierID = s.SupplierID
AND ps.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
AND ps.ProductID = ob.ProductID
AND b.BranchID = 1
AND o.OrderDate >= '2015-01-09'
AND o.OrderDate <= '2015-09-09'
Group By b.BranchName, ps.Price
```

I don't know how to get the sum of another sum. All the keys are correct. If I removed the first sum like this,
    SELECT b.BranchName, SUM(ob.FirstQty + ob.SecondQty)* ps.Price TotalCost
It's working but it shows multiple costs such as 100, 200, 300, etc. What I want is the sum (total costs) of those multiple costs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ps.Price` from the `GROUP BY` clause and do the multiplication with price inside the SUM function (using an extra pair of parentheses).

The query becomes this:

```
SELECT b.BranchName, SUM((ob.FirstQty + ob.SecondQty) * ps.Price) TotalCost
FROM Branch b, Product_Supplier ps, Product p, Supplier s, Order o, Order_Details od
WHERE o.BranchID = b.BranchID
AND o.OrderID = ob.OrderID
AND ob.ProductID = p.ProductID
AND p.FirstSupplierID = s.SupplierID
AND ps.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
AND ps.ProductID = ob.ProductID
AND b.BranchID = 1
AND o.OrderDate >= '2015-01-09'
AND o.OrderDate <= '2015-09-09'
Group By b.BranchName
```